# querying Json attribute fields in Laravel models with elequent builder

Tags: json, laravel

i want to filter a json field (post) in database with elequent builder.

i need help with querying with elequent.

```
attributes: array:17 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "admin_id" => 0
    "email" => "test@gmail.com"
    "fullname" => "asdasdasd"
    "subject" => "asdasdasdasd"
    "desc" => """
      sadasd\r\n
      """
    "cell_phone" => "091200000000"
    **"post" => "{"modir": 0, "saken": 0, "ozv_modir": 0}"**
    "elevator_spec" => null
    "type" => null
    "control" => null
    "count_stop" => null
    "door_type" => null
    "lift_capacity" => null
    "insurance" => null
    "created_at" => "2017-10-28 21:24:54"
    "updated_at" => "2017-10-28 21:24:54"
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
You should use setter and getter in the model in case of that specific field that you want .

     public function setPostAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['post'] = json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }

   public function getPostAttribute()
    {
        $model = new $this;
        $jsonToConvert = $this->attributes['post'];
        $modelArray = $model->fromJson($jsonToConvert);

        return $model->newInstance($modelArray);
    }


after that in your controller :

    Orders::where('post->modir', 0)->get(
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides a simple way for you, use [Array & JSON Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'post' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

Once the cast is defined, you may access the options attribute and it will automatically be deserialized from `JSON` into a `PHP array`. When you set the value of the options attribute, the given array will automatically be serialized back into `JSON` for storage:

```
$user->post = ['modir' => 'blabla'];
$user->save();
```

Comment: the question was about filtering the json data not about saving it . please pay attention